# Xamarin - Android 13 Notification Permission Prompt

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

As we know, Android 13 is introducing runtime notification permission. Here's the [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) on this.

We already have a priming page where we show the notification permission prompt in iOS. We just need to do this for all users on Android 13.

After reading the documentation, i've added the following:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>`

However I can't seem to find a way to prompt Android users. Has anyone had any success with this/can point me in the right direction?

Also, we've noticed all of our users who have upgraded to Android 13 have notifications turned off by default. Is there a way we can add a link to the notifications permission in the settings?

Answer (score 11):

I am currently using this to achieve that, in your MainActivity put this

```
protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            const int requestLocationId = 0;

            string[] notiPermission =
            {
                Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications
            };

            if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33) return;

            if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
            {
                this.RequestPermissions(notiPermission, requestLocationId);
            }
        }
```

Comment: RequestPermissions is exceuted but popup not showing. I have done the same but not working. Tested in both real device and emulator (android 13 ). Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Working on Android 13 with Xamarin.Essentials.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageWriteSettings);
    intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"package:{Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName}"));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```